# Sum Variable in While Loop, based on results of IF statement

Tags: php, variables, if-statement, while-loop, sum

got another question...

I have the following while loop working:

```
    $activityreport = "SELECT $fieldname FROM $table WHERE QuoteID=$quoteid";

    $activity = mysql_query($activityreport) or die(mysql_error());

    while($data = mysql_fetch_array($activity)){

    $amount = $data[$fieldname];

    if($amount>0 && $table != 'OptionFees'){ 
        $amountc = abs($amount);
        }
        elseif($amount>0 && $table == 'OptionFees'){
        $amountd = abs($amount);
        }
        elseif($amount<0 && $table == 'OptionFees'){
            $amountc = abs($amount);
        }
        else{
            $amountd = abs($amount);
        }

    $totald = $totald + $amountd;
    $totalc = $totalc + $amountc;

    echo "<tr><td class='description'>$table</td>
            <td class='debit'>".money_format('%(#10n', $amountd)."</td>
            <td class='credit'>".money_format('%(#10n', $amountc)."</td></tr>";

    }
```

My issue is that $totald and $totalc are ending up with just the results from the last trip through the while loop, not the total of all trips as desired.

**If it weren't for the IF statements breaking down $data[$fieldname], I could just use $total += $data[$fieldname]**, but the breakdown is important.  As you can see, I'm using this to create a table which will display GL accounts and their respective debits and credits for a journal entry.  The lines for each account display perfectly, but the total just show a repeat of the last line.

Any help would be very, very much appreciated!

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I'll check it out.  Not that your comment had anything at all to do with the question I asked... Gotta love drive-bys, though.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize those variables before you start your loop:

```
$activityreport = "SELECT $fieldname FROM $table WHERE QuoteID=$quoteid";

$activity = mysql_query($activityreport) or die(mysql_error());

$totald = 0;
$totalc = 0;

while($data = mysql_fetch_array($activity)){

$amount = $data[$fieldname];
$amountc = 0;
$amountd = 0;

if($amount>0 && $table != 'OptionFees'){ 
    $amountc = abs($amount);
    }
    elseif($amount>0 && $table == 'OptionFees'){
    $amountd = abs($amount);
    }
    elseif($amount<0 && $table == 'OptionFees'){
        $amountc = abs($amount);
    }
    else{
        $amountd = abs($amount);
    }

$totald = $totald + $amountd;
$totalc = $totalc + $amountc;

echo "<tr><td class='description'>$table</td>
        <td class='debit'>".money_format('%(#10n', $amountd)."</td>
        <td class='credit'>".money_format('%(#10n', $amountc)."</td></tr>";

}
```

Comment: Hmm interesting article, I'll think about it. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Yeah, I was doing that with this, above $activityreport:    $totald = 0;
 $totalc = 0;
 $amountd = 0;
 $amountc = 0;
 $activity = 0;
 
Does it need to be after $activity?

Comment: No it doesn't, it should just be before loop. So i guess it doesn't work, maybe try initializing `$amountd` and `$amountc` just after while (and before if)?

Comment: no change...  It's driving me crazy.  I've added the $totald = $totald + $amountd; into the specific If statements, just in case, but that didn't change anything either...

Comment: figured it out, this while loop was inside a much larger one.  I moved the declaration of $totald and $totalc outside of THAT while loop (and all loops) and voila!  works perfectly now.